# Django Heroku collect static configuration error

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

When running git heroku push master, I'm getting two errors/messages:

```
Collectstatic configuration error. To debug, run: 
remote: $ heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

My app deploys successfully in spite of this. Then, I'm getting a message to upgrade pip to the latest version (7.1.2) even though it's already upgraded:

```
You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 7.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I have two settings files - one for local and one for production

**settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'                       
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),
)
```

**settings_production.py**

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

**wsygi.py**

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE",
"viewelsewhere.settings_production")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

Seems to be in working order according to heroku docs here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

If I try to debug and run:

```
heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No
module named psycopg2
```

From what I understand, this is tied to Postgresql but I'm using sqlite3 on my local and want to use Postgresql on production.

I'm so close to pushing my app live and would love help with this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well psycopg2 must be needed to use whitenoise :

run `pip install psycopg2` in your console,
then make sure you have `psycopg2==2.5.3` (or whatever is the version you downloaded)in your requirements.txt file,

then try to push again and see what it says.

Comment: Thanks! I added psycopg2==2.5.3 to my requirements.txt and it installed it during the push to heroku. However, I'm still getting the collectstatic error. Now, when I run, heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --noinput, I'm getting this error: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/viewelsewhere/static'. Where is this directory being referenced?

Comment: it is the place where you should put all your static file so in your viewelsewhere file just create a folder named static and put your static files in it, if it style doesn't work, try replacing your static root with `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')` even if heroku doc states otherwise